# Wifi is disabled on Acer Aspire 4752

Tags: networking, wireless, acer

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer Aspire 4752 and can't get internet to work.

Tried both WiFi and LAN. `rfkill` sees two adapters: `acer-wireless` (actually LAN) has nothing blocked, and `phy0` is hard blocked.

I guess the problem is that i need drivers, but i can't figure out where to get them. Wifi card is Atheros ar9287, LAN Broadcom bcm57785.

`lshw -C network` says wifi is disabled. My laptop has NO INTERNET, so I need to download whatever I need to download using my phone.

What should I do?

Comment: *phy0 hard blocked* is the problem, Find the wireless button, sometimes called Airplane Mode, and switch it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's not airplane mode. If i press fn+f3 it says airplane mode is on, i disable it and nothing changes.

Comment: Please run: `lsmod` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DHTX5QW3kq/

Comment: I've solved the issue by blacklisting acer_wmi and rfkill unblock all after. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ffffgg Please consider posting an answer by clicking the "answer your question" button below to help future readers. It's absolutely fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> I've solved the issue by blacklisting `acer_wmi` and `rfkill unblock all` after.

Source: A [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073710/wifi-is-disabled-on-acer-aspire-4752#comment1762107_1073710).